# Ambiguous redirect ERROR when trying to loop through a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=${PATH[*]}:.
#filename: testScript

while read line; do
    #.
    #.
    #.

done < "$1"
```

And this text file(called file.txt):

```
I am a proud sentence.
```

And when I do:

```
chmod +x ./testScript.txt

./testScript.txt < ./file.txt > output.txt
```

I get this:

```
./testScript.txt: line 11: $1: ambiguous redirect
```

However, if I replace $1 with `file.txt` in `testScript` it works just fine.

How do I make it treat $1 as the file name I send? (file.txt)

Comment: `PATH` is not an array; `${PATH[*]}` expands the same as `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` isn't defined because you haven't passed an argument to your script; you've redirected its input. Either call your script as

```
./testscript.txt ./file.txt > output.txt
```

or, better yet, just let your script read from standard input:

```
while read line; do
    ...
done
```

When you call `./testScript < ./file.txt > output.txt`, your `while` loop will read from its standard input, which is inherited from `./testScript`, which reads from `./file.txt`.

Comment: Hi. That indeed solved it. Although, when I do hat you said, I get: `./testScript.txt: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token done ./testScript.txt: line 11: done < "$1"' `

Comment: That probably indicates a problem with the code inside the `while` loop.

Comment: There is literally nothing inside the loop :)

Comment: That's a problem; you can't have a completely empty loop; you need at least one command, which can be the do-nothing `:` command. `while read line; do done` is illegal; `while read line; do :; done` is fine.

Comment: Brilliant. Got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `< ./file.txt` by `./file.txt`.

Comment: It now gives me:
`./testScript.txt: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `done' `
`./testScript.txt: line 11: `done < "$1"'`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your while loop as followed,

```
while read line; do
.
.
.
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

`${1:-...}` takes `$1` if it's defined otherwise the file name of the standard input of the own process is used.